# Keyboard shortcut to toggle touchpad

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad

My problem is about `if` command.

I have tried to type this in console:

```
if gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled; then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true; fi
```

But this seems to disable the touchpad although it is yet disabled.

Typing `help if` I have learned that the commands after the word `then` are executed when the output of the command after the word `if` is 0 (instead of true, as usual in other programming lenguages).

How can I write a command that toggles the touchpad then?

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu 16.04 "No such schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to evaluate the output (not the exit code) of `gsettings`:

```
if $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled); then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true; fi
```